# Cyrillic characters show up as '?' in PDF when using XeTeX

Tags: xetex, cyrillic

I've looked at many similar questions on TeX overflow to no avail. I've tried using both the polyglossia and the babel packages but neither had any effect. I'm assuming the issue lies a little deeper.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{LMR12R-Gregory}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\begin{document}
        
    \textrussian{Привет!}
    
\end{document}
```

Below is shown the text on the PDF generated by this code:

[image: The text on the PDF]

What causes this? The font has both latin and cyrillic characters. In WordPad it works correctly, so I'm not sure what's going on. Any help would be highly appreciated.

As per the comments below, here is a dropbox link to the font: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4grjkah8x6ldgul/LMR12R-Gregory.ttf?dl=0

Here is a pastebin of the log. There were no issues or errors shown in TeXStudio.
https://pastebin.com/jCx7w7s1

Comment: if xetex doesn't show cyrillic it is quite probable that the font doesn't have the chars - applications like wordpad often use fallbacks in such cases.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for adding a minimal example. It would help answer the question if the font were available. Barring that, can you add `\tracinglostchars=2` and/or look in the log file for warnings about the font not containing the requested characters?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks! I've updated the post.

Comment: The file works for me with no issues (the font looks like a stylized/italic/cursive one.) Check the encoding in TeXStudio: is it using UTF-8 or something else?

Comment: Here is the [picture of what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXXfy.png)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks, it was the encoding in TeXStudio. No idea how it got changed off of default. I've written an answer to my question below

Answer (score 1):

ShreevatsaR found the issue - the encoding of TeXStudio was ISO-8859-1/latin1 instead of UTF-8. For anyone else with this issue, to change the encoding, go to the Edit menu and select "Change Encoding". UTF-8 should be at the top (you may have to scroll up to see it)

Comment: TeXstudio supports “[magic comments](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION_TEXCOM)”. While I generally do not use TeXstudio, I begin most of my documents with `% !TEX TS-program = xelatex` and `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8`, as quite a few compilers support this syntax.